# How does Windows decide what an "App" is in Task Manager? C++

Tags: c++, windows, process, taskmanager

This is more of a general question.

My friend and I have been working on a long-term project. We are trying to find a way to get certain running windows/processes. We are currently using EnumWindows to filter all the running windows, but a lot of what is returned we do not want displayed in our program. The Windows Task Manager, under processes  (first tab), has a list of different processes currently running broken into two categories (Apps and Background Processes). We would like to only get those that the Task Manager recognizes as "Apps".

Is there a way to do this (filter the windows/processes to only grab "Apps") either by grabbing the info from the Task Manager, or by doing it yourself? Any feedback on how we can go about that is much appreciated!

Thank you.

I am running Windows 8.1 if that is of any relevance.

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: I recommend removing the C++ tag since Apps and Processes can be written in any language.  Your question has nothing to do with the C++ language (you haven't mentioned it in your question).

Comment: We are writing it in C++, it is also stated in question. Other languages can do things very differently so it would not be helpful for us to get advice in other languages. Especially if we have no prior experience in that language. Thank you for the feedback though.

Comment: Isn't that just a list of processes that have some sort of main window (including console), that the current user has started?  Can you show an example of something `EnumWindows` returned but should be filtered out?

Comment: Check the edit above. All three of those (MS_WebcheckMonitor, WNPGeneric, and DWM Notification Window) are examples of windows we do not want (and want to filter out). We just want those in the "Apps" area of Task Manager really (and their instances). We also get a lot of IME (and Default IME) from EnumWindows which we are not sure of what they are, but do not want them.

Comment: I think you'll find the windows in question aren't visible.  Task Manager presumably only shows visible windows.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Is there a way to check for visibility? I am going to look that up now, but any knowledge you have would be helpful.

Comment: @Jaromando Have you found a solution to this yet?

Comment: No I haven't, I put it on the back burner